# Debug assertion failed when moving from vs 2013 express to 2015 community

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a project that was running fine in vs 2013 windows express. I get this error when I run it in vs 2015 community. I have been googling for about an hour and have yet to find anything relevant. I hope someone can give some ideas on how I can fix this. I don't think I can post my code here because it is large with multiple files. But if posting the small function at which it crashes does help then here it is

```
void process (const Mat& binMask, vector<Rect>& players, vector<Point>& ball) {
            vector<vector<Point>> contours;
            findContours(binMask, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
            //findContours(image, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

            vector<vector<Point>> players_cand, ball_cand;
            filterAndSortRoi_Geom(contours, players_cand, ball_cand);

            //drawContours(frame, players_cand, -1, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 4);
            //drawContours(frame, ball_cand, -1, CV_RGB(0, 0, 255), 4);
            cout << players_cand.size();
            vector<vector<Point>>::const_iterator it = players_cand.begin();
            while (it != players_cand.end()) {
                players.push_back(boundingRect(*it));
                ++it;
            }

            it = ball_cand.begin();
            while (it != ball_cand.end()) {
                Rect r = boundingRect(*it);
                Point p (r.x + r.width/2, r.y + r.height/2);
                ball.push_back(p);
                ++it;
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you linked to OpenCV compiled with vc14? I guess not ;D

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "running in Visual Studio"? Did you rebuild the whole project in VS 2015? Did you also upgrade the OpenCV libraries, so that you're not linking to the version built for VS2013?

Comment: Hi I have OpenCV compiled with vc14. I have another project on reconstruction which was fine on vs 2015 community. I have brought the property sheets over from that project to this on object tracking. Do you reckon its an OpenCV issue ? I will look through the settings again to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your `Additional Library Directories` to use VS2015 libraries. I guess your current option value is `\x64\vc12\lib` or `\x86\vc12\lib`. These libraries are for Visual Studio 2013. Open CV 2.4 doesn't have precompiled libraries for VS2015, so you should compile it by yourself.